# How to make rust compiler prevent me from calling a function with an argument value of zero?

Tags: rust, assert, compile-time

Quite simply, I have a setter method on a struct that sets a field value of type `i32` and I don't want to allow zero or negative numbers.  I have achieved this with an `assert!` macro like so:

```
pub fn set_myfield(&mut self, arg: i32) {
    assert!(arg > 0);
    self.myfield = arg;
}
```

This appears to cause a panic *at runtime* if the caller calls `set_myfield(0)`, but gives no error at compile time.  Is there any kind of assertion I can write so that consumers of my library will get an error *at compile time* if their code tries to call this method with a zero or negative input?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand which use case would be this, if this function is exposed in a lib I guess users won't be passing only hardcoded values, the input value will be revealed at runtime in most cases I guess... maybe panic is not the best solution but I don't think you can avoid an error handling at runtime. You could create a custom type with a constraint and ensure the value at instanciation but I don't see how this would be possible at compile time.

Comment: What should happen if someone passes in a variable that can't be statically ensured to be nonzero?

Comment: The usual Rust approach is to write some wrapper class `NonZero(i32)` that refuses to allow construction with a zero value. Any caller is required to `try_from` to construct that class, and handle the error as they see fit. That way by the time you get to here, it's basically impossible to call this function incorrectly. A panic is rude. Let the caller figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust, there is no way to specify a *subset* of a type's values as a type. However, you can define new types which enforce rules, or use existing ones, and there is even an existing type for the rule you want: [`std::num::NonZeroI32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/num/struct.NonZeroI32.html).

```rust
pub fn set_myfield(&mut self, arg: NonZeroI32) {
    self.myfield = arg.get();
}
```

Now, in a sense, this doesn't change anything — there's still going to be a run-time check for constructing `NonZeroI32`. However, it means that:

- Your function states its requirement in the type system rather than the documentation.
- Your function doesn't ever panic.
- The caller can choose to make the check *earlier* than when it calls `set_myfield`, which may simplify error handling paths.

And, in future versions of Rust, it may be possible to (when applicable) define constants of nonzero types, making everything truly compile-time checked.

```rust
use std::num::NonZeroI32;

const FOUR: NonZeroI32 = NonZeroI32::new(4).unwrap();
```

(Right now, this code doesn't compile because `Option::unwrap()` is not available in `const` evaluation.)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is something like [Zig's `comptime`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#comptime) feature.

But in Rust, if you're trying to defend against literal `0` value at *compile time*, you can use `macro_rules` and the built-in `compile_error!` macro.

Here is a working example ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=363a775a25e61d2add07a2de5eb2a140)):

```rust
struct Foo {
    myarg: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { myarg: 1 }
    }

    pub fn set_myfield(&mut self, arg: Arg) {
        self.myarg = arg.0;
    }
}

struct Arg(i32);

macro_rules! make_arg {
    (0) => {
        compile_error!("Zero is not a valid value")
    };
    ($val:expr) => {
        Arg($val)
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new();

    // This one succeeds, as expected
    let arg = make_arg!(42);
    foo.set_myfield(arg);

    // This will fail to COMPILE with error above: "Zero is not a valid value"
    // let arg = make_arg!(0); // Will fail to compile
    // foo.set_myfield(arg);

    // However, this one succeeds
    let v = 0;
    let arg = make_arg!(v);
    foo.set_myfield(arg);
}
```

You can move `Arg` to its own module to prevent users from setting its internal value directly.